# Nunit: Check that two objects are the same

Tags: c#, nunit

I have an object

```
 public class Foo
            {
                public string A{ get; set; }
                public string B{ get; set; }
            }
```

I am comparing the return value from the SUT when it returns null for A and B like this.

```
Assert.That(returnValue, Is.EqualTo(new Foo { A = null, B = null}));
```

This did not work, so I tried

```
Assert.That(returnValue, Is.SameAs(new Foo { A = null, B = null}));
```

This didn't work either.

I get a message like

```
 Expected: same as <Namespace+Foo>
 But was:  <Namespace+Foo>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you checking that the values are the same or the object reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [nunit documentation](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=equalConstraint&r=2.5.5),

> When checking the equality of user-defined classes, NUnit makes use of the Equals override on the expected object. If you neglect to override Equals, you can expect failures non-identical objects. In particular, overriding operator== without overriding Equals has no effect.

You can however supply your own comparer to test if the values are equal for the properties.

> If the default NUnit or .NET behavior for testing equality doesn't meet your needs, you can supply a comparer of your own through the Using modifier. When used with EqualConstraint, you may supply an IEqualityComparer, IEqualityComparer, IComparer, IComparer; or Comparison as the argument to Using.

```
Assert.That( myObj1, Is.EqualTo( myObj2 ).Using( myComparer ) );
```

So in this case your comparer would be

```
    public class FooComparer : IEqualityComparer
    {
        public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
        {
            if (x.A == y.A && x.B == y.B)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Foo inst)
        {
            return inst.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Nunit is comparing the two objects objects by reference so it is showing the two objects are not equal. You will have to override the `Equals` method in your object class.